# Fast low resolution clock based on interval signal timer

Tags: c, time, signals, setitimer

I need a fast and portable low resolution (~10 ms) clock to implement timeouts in a high-rps app. Even using `clock_gettime` results in an unacceptable reduction in rps. I decided to create my own low-resolution clock based on `setitimer` with 10 ms interval and benchmarks showed that it had almost no effect on rps. But I still have some concerns - at the very least, I haven't seen this approach anywhere. Could you tell me if there are any pitfalls with this approach?

Comment: It'll be easier to advice if you show a [mre] of the setup you've got

Comment: If you also show the code that was not acceptable, maybe we can suggest improvements.

Comment: What about `timerfd_create(2)`?